# Отключить индексирования каталога в macOS

Tags: macos, файловая-система

Есть каталог на диске где храниться около миллиона файлов и возможно отключить индексирования данного каталога?

(просто возможно macOS запускает процессы по индексации каталогов и из-за этого происходят тормоза)

> Информация о машине:
>
> macOS v10.12.5,
> HDD c MacOS Extended (журналируемый)

Comment: В очереди проверок кто-то пометил вопрос как "не по теме". Вполне по теме товарищи: ru-so это программирование и системное администрирование, здесь чётко вторая категория видна.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System Preferences -> Spolight -> Privacy

Добавьте в исключения Вашу папку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, как не странно это помогло, странно правда то что практически не пользуюсь Spolight

Comment: Я с помощью Spotlight открываю программы cmd+space (точно не уверен... менял дефолтные настройки) и начинаю вводить имя требуемого приложения и/или документа. Мне нравится больше чем MissionControl. Хотя дело вкуса.

Comment: Я перешел с Spotlight на Alfred и по этому не особо вижу в нем смысла,  с Alfred можно искать почти везде и интеграция с iTerm, Dash и не особо сложно написать плагин для вывода ответа сразу на stackoverflow (Да хоть Docker контейнер собирать и дэплоить на бой), хотя из минусов со временем это превратилось в свой метоязык который понимаешь только ты. (это было немного рекламы xD)